# How to check an event in another method in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, method-call

In my project I want to select a file in server and send to clients in java swing. In this I must send to the client which I like in the radio button for clients. But I don't know how to check the radio button is clicked in the send button. As I must check the radio button is clicked in send button method.

My radio button code

```
jRadioButton1.setText("One");
jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
  }
});
}


private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Selected Button 1");
}
```

For send button......

```
    jButton1.setText("SEND");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {

    jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
    Object k=evt.getSource();
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

How to check the radiobutton is clicked in send action method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your different UI components are in the same class and declared as instance members, you can simply reference them anywhere within your class. So you could write:

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("radio button selected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("radio button NOT selected");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: not my friend and thanks. I will try and give the opinion. :D

Comment: I believe OP just wants to check the state of the radio button at the time the `Send` button is clicked.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I see what you mean... The proposed code makes no sense.

Comment: @assylias I did the same but no action is performed when I click the Send button. So whats the problem?

Comment: @MuralidharanT I think I misunderstood your question. See my edit.